# MSVC++ 2015 - SSE compiler bug or bug/undefined behavior in my program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, sse

I ran into some weird behavior while working on a SIMD color lerp function, and I trimmed it down into a minimal program. The SIMD code in this example no longer performs a lerp but it performs unpacking from a 32-bit color to an XMM register and then back to 32-bit.

In MSVC++ 2015 (Update 3), in Release x64 mode, the following code does not produce the correct result, but in Debug x64 or Release/Debug x86 it works correctly.  This is the only code in an otherwise empty Win32 C++ console application project:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "emmintrin.h"

struct Color4
{
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t alpha;

    Color4(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue, uint8_t alpha = 255)
        : red(red), green(green), blue(blue), alpha(alpha) {}

    explicit Color4(uint32_t rgba)
    {
        red = (uint8_t)(rgba & 0xFF);
        green = (uint8_t)((rgba >> 8)&0xFF);
        blue = (uint8_t)((rgba >> 16) & 0xFF);
        alpha = (uint8_t)((rgba >> 24) & 0xFF);
    }
};

Color4 PackUnpack(Color4 col)
{
    uint32_t tmp;

    memcpy(&tmp, &col, sizeof(tmp));

    __m128 aFloat = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(
        _mm_unpacklo_epi16(
            _mm_unpacklo_epi8(
                _mm_set1_epi32(tmp),
                _mm_setzero_si128()
            ),
            _mm_setzero_si128()
        )
    );

    __m128i ret = _mm_packus_epi16(
        _mm_packs_epi32(
            _mm_cvtps_epi32(aFloat),
            _mm_setzero_si128()
        ),
        _mm_setzero_si128()
    );

    return Color4((uint32_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(ret));
}

int main()
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    printf("DEBUG\n");
#else
    printf("RELEASE\n");
#endif

    Color4 c = PackUnpack(Color4(32, 64, 128, 255));

    // Debug x64 or Debug/Release x86: Prints "32 64 128 255"
    // Release x64: Prints "255 0 0 0"
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",  c.red, c.green, c.blue, c.alpha);

    return 0;
}
```

The Release x64 output is:

```
RELEASE
255 0 0 0
```

Debug x64 and all x86 output is:

```
DEBUG
32 64 128 255
```

The disassembly looks like it's messed up pre-computing a constant value to load into an XMM register to skip the `_mm_set1_epi32` (see first `movdqa` instruction.)

```
main:
00007FF674391070  sub         rsp,38h  
00007FF674391074  lea         rcx,[string "RELEASE\n" (07FF674392200h)]  
00007FF67439107B  call        printf (07FF674391010h)  
00007FF674391080  movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [__xmm@000000ff000000ff000000ff000000ff (07FF674392220h)]  
00007FF674391088  lea         rcx,[string "%d %d %d %d\n" (07FF674392210h)]  
00007FF67439108F  xorps       xmm2,xmm2  
00007FF674391092  mov         dword ptr [rsp+40h],0FF804020h  
00007FF67439109A  punpcklbw   xmm0,xmm2  
00007FF67439109E  punpcklwd   xmm0,xmm2  
00007FF6743910A2  cvtdq2ps    xmm0,xmm0  
00007FF6743910A5  cvtps2dq    xmm1,xmm0  
00007FF6743910A9  packssdw    xmm1,xmm2  
00007FF6743910AD  packuswb    xmm1,xmm2  
00007FF6743910B1  movd        r10d,xmm1  
00007FF6743910B6  mov         edx,r10d  
00007FF6743910B9  mov         r8d,r10d  
00007FF6743910BC  shr         edx,10h  
00007FF6743910BF  mov         eax,r10d  
00007FF6743910C2  shr         r8d,8  
00007FF6743910C6  movzx       r9d,dl  
00007FF6743910CA  shr         eax,18h  
00007FF6743910CD  movzx       edx,r10b  
00007FF6743910D1  movzx       r8d,r8b  
00007FF6743910D5  mov         dword ptr [rsp+20h],eax  
00007FF6743910D9  call        printf (07FF674391010h)  
00007FF6743910DE  xor         eax,eax  
00007FF6743910E0  add         rsp,38h  
00007FF6743910E4  ret
```

I have tried this with `g++` 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and it works fine with `-O3` on or off.

So my question is, **is this a compiler bug, the result of using undefined/implementation defined behavior, or a more mundane bug in my code?**

(The code used to use type punning via unions to get the uint32_t value out of the Color4, which I replaced with a memcpy because that's not standard... still no dice.)

Comment: That might help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3207317/visual-c-optimizer-fixes-for-visual-studio-2015-update-3

Comment: The unexpected behavior is the same in VS 2017

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug.  What happens if you use `tmp = color.red + 256 * (col.blue + 256 * (col.green + 256 * col.alpha)));` instead of the `memcpy`?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Thanks for the tip, I downloaded & installed this but it does not seem to have fixed it. :(

@1201ProgramAlarm When I replace that line with `tmp = col.red + 256 * (col.blue + 256 * (col.green + 256 * col.alpha));` it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Not actually an answer, but, since I don't like to put too much text into the comment, this the smallest code I could reproduce the issue with:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "emmintrin.h"

int main()
{
    uint8_t src[4] = { 32, 64, 128, 255 };

    uint32_t tmp = 0;
    memcpy( &tmp, &src, sizeof( tmp ) );    

    auto a = _mm_set1_epi32( tmp );

    printf( "tmp = 0x%08x\n", tmp );
    printf( "a.m128i_i32[0] = 0x%08x\n", a.m128i_i32[0] );  

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
tmp = 0xff804020
a.m128i_i32[0] = 0xff804020
```

Output with Release x64:

```
tmp = 0xff804020
a.m128i_i32[0] = 0x000000ff
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this together.

Comment: Tinkering around a little more leads to finding that the value that lands in the SSE register is actually the 4th byte of the array. Interesting :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a compiler bug.  A workaround is to use

```
tmp = color.red + 256 * (col.blue + 256 * (col.green + 256 * col.alpha)));
```

in place of the `memcpy` or type punning.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm a little shocked to have hit a real compiler bug so I'm going to leave this open for a little while longer in case anyone can prove otherwise, but if they can't I'll mark this one as Accepted! :) (and file with MS.)

Comment: Is there a bug already filed about this, or is this being a compiler bug a casual observation?

Comment: I don't know if it is filed, but the generated code being wrong would be a bug.